# Compare dictionary <string,List<string>> single value with a list of values c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, dictionary

parse the xml and form dictionary with same key for multiple values

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

doc.Load(confidencethresholdFilePath + "\\input.xml");
// XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/root/file");
doc.Normalize();
XmlNodeList nList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("key");
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.Count; temp++)
{
    string keyvalue = "";
    XmlNode nNode = nList.Item(temp);
    List<String> main = new List<string>();
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(main);
    XmlElement ele = (XmlElement)nNode;
    keyvalue = ele.GetAttribute("value");
    for (int i = 0; i < ele.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ele.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes.Count == 1)
        {
            Double sec = Double.Parse(ele.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
            int seg = TimeToSegment(sec);
            Console.WriteLine("" + seg);
            main.Add(Convert.ToString(seg));
        }
    }
    dictionary.Add(keyvalue, main);
}
```

I want to comapare with single value but it shows error
 `dictionary.ContainsValue(s.sname)` invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to check but if you are trying to match keys then do this:

```
dictionary.ContainsKey(s.sname);
```

Or you might try:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>> ienKeyVals = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(s.sname));
```

> parse the xml and form dictionary with same key for multiple values

A dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys. Its not possible to add duplicate items to a Dictionary - an alternative is to use the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

[Enumerable.ToLookup Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx)

> Creates a generic Lookup from an IEnumerable.